# Move grandchildren elements in CSS grid-template-areas items around

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to learn about `grid-template-areas`.

But my code is not working like the intended area template:

> "title title"
> "both-a both-b"
> "left-a right-a"
> "left-b right-b"

All left items should be to the left of the corresponding ("a" or "b") right items.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title"
                       "both-a both-b"                       
                       "left-a right-a"
                       "left-b right-b";
}

.wrapper > header {
  grid-area: title;
}

.both > .topic-a {
  grid-area: both-a;  
}

.both > .topic-b {
  grid-area: both-b;  
}

.left > .topic-a {
  grid-area: left-a;
}

.left > .topic-b {
  grid-area: left-b;
}

.right > .topic-a {
  grid-area: right-a;
}

.right > .topic-b {
  grid-area: right-b;
}


.left-side {
  color: red;
}

.right-side {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article class="wrapper">
<header><h1>Title</h1></header>

<section class="both">
<section class="topic-a">
<ol>
<li>both-A 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
</ol>
</section>
<section class="topic-b">
<ol>
<li>both-B 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
</ol>
</section>
</section>

<section class="left-side">
<section class="topic-a">
<ol>
<li>left-A 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
</ol>
</section>
<section class="topic-b">
<ol>
<li>left-B 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
</ol>
</section>
</section>

<section class="right-side">
<section class="topic-a">
<ol>
<li>right-A 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
</ol>
</section>
<section class="topic-b">
<ol>
<li>right-B 1st item</li>
<li>2nd item</li>
<li>3rd item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
<li>nth item</li>
</ol>
</section>
</section>

</article>
```

I know it's probably a silly mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: grid is only working on a parent-child relationship. You are giving grid-area style to grand-children of the grid, this won't work.

Comment: @vals Ah, I see! Thanks for the heads-up! Should I nest grids then? Or maybe flexboxes? Although, the problem remains, these are children of different sections... maybe I should just delete the parents and make them children instead of grandchildren

Comment: Well, the decision is yours ... But probably you should nest flexboxes inside the grid, given the layout that I can see

Comment: @vals But is it possible to have grandchildren as flex-items? I'm trying without success to make a flexbox

Comment: Finally I found this: "... container's display property to flex or inline-flex. As soon as we do this the **direct children** of that container *become flex items*. " https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox . So I don't think a flexbox is possible, there's no common parent for `left-side` and `right-side`, to make left-a be on the left side of right-a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, maybe this will help someone.

It's not possible to do what I want, because both CSS `flexbox` and `grid` only have direct **children** as items (so *grandchildren* are not possible items).

Therefore, I had to exclude two sections and put both left-ab and right-ab under a same parent. This way, I can have `left-a` next to `right-a`, and `left-b` next to `right-b`.

This is the resulting code:
(my CSS skills are very poor, corrections would be very welcome!)

```css
* {
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title" "both" "left-right";
}

.wrapper>header {
  grid-area: title;
}

.both {
  grid-area: both;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.both>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.left-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.left-right>* {
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 40%;
}

.both>.topic-a {
  order: 1;
}

.both>.topic-b {
  order: 2;
}

.topic-a.left-side {
  order: 3;
}

.topic-b.left-side {
  order: 5;
}

.topic-a.right-side {
  order: 4;
}

.topic-b.right-side {
  order: 6;
}

.left-side {
  color: red;
  background-color: #FCC;
}

.right-side {
  color: blue;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<article class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="both">
    <section class="topic-a">
      <ol>
        <li>both-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b">
      <ol>
        <li>both-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </section>

  <div class="left-right">


    <section class="topic-a left-side">
      <ol>
        <li>left-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b left-side">
      <ol>
        <li>left-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>



    <section class="topic-a right-side">
      <ol>
        <li>right-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b right-side">
      <ol>
        <li>right-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>


  </div>

</article>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can bypass **child (2nd level)** elements by using `display: contents;` in it. Thus **grandchild (3rd level)** elelments will be affected from the **parent (1st level)** grid.

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "title title" "both-a both-b" "left-a right-a" "left-b right-b";
}

.both,
.left-side,
.right-side {
  display: contents; /* Bypass direct Child */
}

.wrapper>header {
  grid-area: title;
}

.both>.topic-a {
  grid-area: both-a;
}

.both>.topic-b {
  grid-area: both-b;
}

.left>.topic-a {
  grid-area: left-a;
}

.left-side>.topic-b {
  grid-area: left-b;
}

.right-side>.topic-a {
  grid-area: right-a;
}

.right-side>.topic-b {
  grid-area: right-b;
}

.left-side {
  color: red;
}

.right-side {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<article class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </header>

  <section class="both">
    <section class="topic-a">
      <ol>
        <li>both-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b">
      <ol>
        <li>both-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="left-side">
    <section class="topic-a">
      <ol>
        <li>left-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b">
      <ol>
        <li>left-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section class="right-side">
    <section class="topic-a">
      <ol>
        <li>right-A 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
    <section class="topic-b">
      <ol>
        <li>right-B 1st item</li>
        <li>2nd item</li>
        <li>3rd item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
        <li>nth item</li>
      </ol>
    </section>
  </section>

</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The only possible issue with `display: contents` is that if you, for example, used `background-color` instead of `color` or added `border` rules to the classes with `display: content` it wouldn't work (you can, of course, use a different selector, like `.left-side li {background: orange;}`)

Comment: I thought this was too good to be true. This gives so much flexibility.

Comment: For some reason, this seems to break `grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit, <len>)` in every browser I've tried.